# filtering pandas where none of the column in blank

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame which looks like below :-

leftmost side of the df:-
[image]

rightmost side of the df :-
[image]

I want to filter row index where none of the columns are blank. I have row index and column index and don't have the column names. I can't rename it because i have two different values in it and i want to rename after filtering.

I am not aware of how to do it so i don't have any code which i have tried.

Comment: It is best in this type of question to create a small sample dataframe with expected outcome... See this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: I think `df = df.dropna(axis=1)` should working.

Comment: How about you just do `df.dropna()`

Comment: none @jezrael that is dropping all the columns where value is

Comment: @AlexandreNixon that works i dont why i didnt think of this simple method but i want to make two df one is with none of the value is null and the other is the remianing value

Comment: @ScottBoston i will keep that in mind from next time.

Comment: df[df.isnull().any(axis=1)] will be the answer

Comment: @ak3191 thanks a lot this is thing what i was looking for.